# Avoiding re-renders for controlled inputs in a React Flux application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, fluxible

I have a classic Flux pattern in my application, using `fluxible`. An input's `value` is tied to my component's prop, and its `onChange` invokes an action, which in turn updates a store, which in turn passes a prop into my component:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  handleChange(e) {
    this.context.executeAction(persist, { value: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return <input value={this.props.value} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>;
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when the store emits a change and the new value gets passed into my component, that causes it to re-render, and the input cursor position is lost (is moved to the end).

I know I can create a custom `shouldComponentUpdate` method for my component, but doing so is somewhat tricky and definitely tedious for what I assume is a very frequently-occuring pattern.

Is there a well-established pattern for avoiding re-renders for controlled inputs?

Comment: It's been a while for me, but I recall all of my forms managing their own state to prevent it from being changed as the user was editing it. Perhaps you could only set the state value when the user has entered in something that does not equal `this.props.value`. Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks @JasonRice, I came to a very similar conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the description of [ReactLink](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html) to give a pretty good pattern for dealing with this sort of thing. Here's what I came up with:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: props.value };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    // If in some cases you want to handle a new value prop, update state here
  }

  handleChange({ target: { value } }) {
    this.setState({ value });
    this.context.executeAction(persist, { value });
  }

  render() {
    return <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>;
  }
}
```

Basically, just ignore the people that say "if you set state based on a prop you're doing it wrong" and set your initial state based on the prop. This state is what your input now uses for its value. Then, assuming that new `value` props do come in, they won't affect your `render` output. If you do want them to, you can add logic to `componentWillReceiveProps`. In my case, for example, I did want to update the input, but only if it wasn't focused:

```
componentWillReceiveProps({ value }) {
  if (!this.state.isFocused) {
    this.setState({ value });
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem with using `isFocused` is that the user will edit an input then go to the next field only to have their previous work undone which would be frustrating. If it was me I would add a reset button that simply clears the state or reinitializes it. (I guess this assumes multiple fields and a submit button)

Comment: That's a great point, @JasonRice. In my case, these foreign prop updates come from a sync process that pulls data from another source at an unpredictable time. Maybe a better check for that scenario is to only replace the content if something hasn't been entered. What I'm coming to realize is that there's probably no good one-size-fits-all scenario, which is why a custom `componentWillReceiveProps`  is necessary.